# Getting a div to responsively take up the rest of a web page width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on learning responsive web design, but have run into a small issue. I have an `<aside>` and a `<section>` side-by-side. I wanted the aside to be the same size and the section to automatically take up the rest of the width. Is this possible?

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <head>

    <body>
        <aside id="sidebar">text</aside>

        <section id="main">main section</section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css.

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;

  margin: -4px;
}

aside{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: -4px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ehftnp3u/

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex`

```css
#container .row {
  display: flex;
}
#container aside {
  width: 150px;
}
#container section {
  flex: 1;
}
#main{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <aside>
      <span>sidebar</span>
    </aside>
    <section id="main">
      <span>main section</span>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For old browser support you can use `display: table` or `float`

Sample using `float`

```css
#container .row:after {     /* clear fix for your float  */
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
#container aside {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
#container section {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
#main{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <aside>
      <span>sidebar</span>
    </aside>
    <section id="main">
      <span>main section</span>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the section and aside behave like table-cells to achieve the effect you want

```css
#container {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#container .row {
  display:table-row;
}
#container aside, #container section {
  display:table-cell
}

aside {
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
}

#main{
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  
  margin: -4px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
  <div id="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <aside>
      <span>sidebar</span>
    </aside>
    <section id="main">
      <span>main section</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I am not using tables for a website layout it is not 2004 and there are most likely better solutions. Tables have to load before the content that resides within them. It is a solution that works, but a poor one at best.

Comment: Do not fall into the Illusory correlation that this is a table. Using the display:table-cell css property you can easily change the layout with CSS in your responsive design.

Comment: Ah sorry, saw the first line and made assumptions. I apologize.

Comment: no worries. LGson's suggestion to us flex is excellent.....although not widely supported he provides a solution that degrades nicely for older browsers (by using display:table as I suggested)....but I need the rep so help me out ;) lol

Answer (score 0):

Just add width in your aside and section as below, this works perfectly on responsive page too.

```
#main{
width:70%;
 }
aside{
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: It works if you want tons of different css files connected to tons of media queries. I am looking to create a single layout.css file and a single home.css file. Trying to consolidate all css into the least amount of files as humanly possible.

Comment: Okay, so hopefully flex worked for you as you have planned.